# Algebraic approach to the length()

Tags: java, math

Let's say there's a String object of length 5:

```
ABCDE
```

and a method definition:

```
public int returnIndex(int n)
{
}
```

How can I return a correct index of the String when a passed value into the parameter is `negative` and counts `backwards` (it should wrap around)? If the length of the mentioned String is 5 and a passed value is -7 so it should return `D`which has index of 3. I tried Math.abs but it doesnt count properly. Could smb please put me on the right track?

Comment: I don't understand the requirement. If you "count backwards" 7 places in a string of length 5, it would just overflow. Or do you mean it should wrap around?

Comment: Quite a pretentious title, isn't it? So Math.abs doesn't count properly: how so?

Comment: This sounds more like a maths question than JAva. I think I understand though

Comment: Have a look at the `%`-operator...

Comment: It should wrap around @Mureinik

Comment: You are trying to make the string acts as a circular one? If yes, take a look at _modular arithmetic_ on google.

Comment: What is the expected character if you pass 3 as index? `C` or `D`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use both Math.abs to make the number positive then you need to use modulus function on the number to take away the length of the string.

See my code below.

```
public static int returnIndex(int n)
{
    String a = "ABCDE";
    n = Math.abs(n) % a.length();
    return a.length() - n;
}
```

What this does is it takes the number, removes the negative symbol, finds the remainder after dividing the length of the string and n and the returns the value of the string length minus n.

This appears to be what you wanted.

As I said in my original comment.

Not a java question, more a maths problem.

Comment: This does not work when you pass `2` as an argument.

Comment: Why not? Returns B for me

Answer (score 0):

The modulo (`%`) operator takes care of most of the "wrap around" problem, although you'd still need some tweaking for negative numbers:

```
public int returnIndex(int n) {
    String s = "ABCDE";
    int length = s.length();
    int result = n % length;
    if (result < 0) {
        result += length;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using java 8 you can use the method [`Math.floorMod(int x, int y)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#floorMod-int-int-).
This method does the wrapping around job and even works for negative numbers.

So your code would be:

```
public int returnIndex(int n) {
        String s = "ABCDE";
        return Math.floorMod(n, s.length());
}
```